# Recuperar atributos CSS inline com PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho DIV's que possuem estilos inline de CSS gerados dinamicamente.

Exemplo: `<div style="top: 275px; left: 563px;"></div>`

Minha duvida é a seguinte, como posso recuperar esses valores "top" e "left" com PHP/Codeigniter de forma que possibilite eu registrar no meu banco de dados posteriormente?

Comment: Retirei a tag CSS porque, ao meu ver, a questão não está relacionada propriamente com CSS.

Comment: De que modo dinâmico esses atributos são gerados?

Comment: Ei Sam, bom dia mestre. Você quer recuperar em tempo de renderização / no envio de formulário / ou através de ação tipo um click em botão?

Comment: Essas divs são geradas a cada clique que o usuário da sobre uma imagem na tela, essas divs são geradas com os atributos CSS inline "top" e "left" referentes a posição do clique.

Answer (score 0):

Se tiver como imprimir um ID para cada uma dessas DIVs, poderia tentar algo nesse sentido:

```
function explodeAttributes($string) {
    return explode(':', $string);
}

$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$html_string = '<div id="div1" style="top: 275px; left: 563px;"></div>';

//methods to load HTML
$domDoc->loadHTML($html_string);
$documentElement = $domDoc->getElementById('div1')->getAttribute('style'); // pega o atributo style
$documentElement = explode(';',$documentElement); // converte os atributos para um array
$documentElement = array_filter($documentElement); // remove os itens vazios do array
$documentElement = array_map("explodeAttributes", $documentElement); // converte as propriedades do CSS para array

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($documentElement);
```

O resultado seria algo como

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => top
            [1] =>  275px
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  left
            [1] =>  563px
        )

)
```

Teste Online:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4f9b95a254ee0546c6a4a152ed0f5d9ac729fc8